# Cannot parse boolean values with argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

Things I have tried but did not work:

1. `parser.add_argument('--download',type=bool,default=False)`
2. `parser.add_argument('--download',default=False,action='store_true')`
3. `parser.add_argument('--download',action='store_true')`

For case 1, Passing `False` also gets interpreted as `True`.
For case 2 and 3, I get the error

`main.py: error: unrecognized arguments: False`

Python version : 3.8

Why does `argparse` not work for boolean arguments?

Comment: The use of `bool` at the `type` function is mentioned in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way ['store_true'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) works is that if you give `--download` as an argument, then the value is true; and if you omit it, it is false.

The reason `type=bool` doesn't work as you want is that any nonempty string passed to the `bool` function will result in True. (You could, if you wanted, write a function that returns True if the string is "True" and False if it is "False", and use that for `type`, but that is not the typical use-case.)